# How to count the number of lines between two points? (ignoring word wrap)

Tags: newlines

Is there a convenient way to count the number of lines between two points?

While I could search for `\n` in a loop and limit it to one of the points, this seems like an overly verbose way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a function to count lines.

`(count-lines beg end)`

*Found this soon after posting.*